# Open/closed/constructible subsets of locally free sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, definitions

(Cross-posted from math.SE since I'm not sure what is a suitable platform. Link on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597258/open-closed-constructible-subsets-of-locally-free-sheaves)

Is there a "canonical" way to define open/closed/constructible subsets of a locally free sheaf/vector bundle $\mathcal{F}$ on a scheme $X$? There is a clear way to do this with topological vector bundles, but are things defined the same way in algebraic geometry?

I came across them in a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05207), but couldn't find any other sources discussing possibly related concepts specifically in algebraic geomery other than those looking at subsets of global sections of these vector bundles.

My guess was that this has something to do with interpreting a locally free sheaf/vector bundle $\mathcal{F}$ locally as (relative) $\text{Spec} (\text{Sym}^\cdot \mathcal{F}^\vee)$ (which are also discussed in section 4 of the paper above), but I'm not sure how to formulate a precise definition other than what was suggested at the beginning of this question. It may be helpful to list interesting examples/non-examples.